# Suppose the probability is $0.3$ that a certain athlete wins in each race. Find the probability that this athlete wins in at most $3$ races.

Tags: probability

I think this is a binomial distribution, not exactly sure. I have $x=3$, $p=0.3$, but I don't know $n$. Can someone please help?

Comment: You can only write the probability in terms of $n$. If $n \leq 3$, for example, the probability is $1$ and it is is certainly not $1$ for other values of $n$.

Comment: How many races are there?

Comment: perhaps it isnt a binomial distribution, for geometric you can still get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a binomial distribution, you cannot get an answer from what you gave.

However, in the case this is a geometric distribution, where the athlete runs race after race and continually advances $P(X \leq 3)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)\\=0.7+0.3(0.7)+0.3^2(0.7)+0.3^3(0.7)=\boxed{0.9919}$

Answer (score 0):

Let X denote the number of races the athlete runs.  Then X is geometric with p = 0.3 and the probability distribution is given by P(X=x)=(0.7)^(x-1)(0.3), x=1,2,...

The athlete win 1/2/3 races with probablity 0.3 so

P(X<=3)=P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)=0.3+0.7(0.3)+(0.7)^2*(0.3)=0.657

;))